# ContentObserver on SMS inbox not working

Tags: android, contentobserver

I start a service that registers `ContentObserver` on the `SMS inbox` like so

```
smsObserver = new SmsObserver(new Handler());
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), true, smsObserver);
```

Here is the class, I just want to know when a change is made to the provider But I dont get the callback to the `onChange` method

```
private class SmsObserver extends ContentObserver{

    public SmsObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange){
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),
                new String[] {"thread_id"},"address" + "=" + from,null,null);
        if(c != null && c.moveToLast()){
            long id = c.getLong(0);
            Log.d("ID", c.getString(0));
        }
        c.close();
    }
}
```

I also register an observer for the Uri `content://mms-sms/conversations` and that one works and I just copied how I did everything from this one over to the SmsObserver class so I dont know whats wrong, can I not set an observer on the `content://sms/inbox`?

Answer (score 1):

-First, register your `ContentObserver` like this:

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/inbox"), true, smsObserver);
```

-Then, override the following method in your `ContentObserver`:

```
@Override    
public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use Broadcast receiver: .
Is necessary register broadcast. See: [Problem with SMS Broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018536/problem-with-sms-broadcast-receiver)

Comment: I have a broadcast receiver that fires when a new SMS comes in but I need to see when the message gets put into the provider, this does not happen right away

Comment: +1 tyczj, there is no existing Intent for outgoing SMS/MMS so we can't catch them with a BroadcastReceiver. We are forced to use an Observer which will be notified of changes (both for received/sent SMS/MMS)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using brodcast receiver, sms is put in to db when brodcast ends. This means you need to fire bg thread and sleep it for litle time and then sms will show in db